# Display the map without submiting the address (Google MAP API V3)<

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In this example!

Online Demo: 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html

Or 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/geocoding-simple.html

You get the map when you put the city or the address manually and click on submit bottom.

**Is there a way to give the address without add it in the form and submitting it?p .**

I get my address from SQL table and want to show the map without any submitting

Comment: you can use server-side and set the var into javascript or u can store the LatLng in a JSON file locally, but since u mention SQL table go w/ first

Comment: how I can set the address into a var (in the example above)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean [geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can easily tweak the code in the example to get the address from a variable rather than from the form field.

That said, if you've got alot of addresses you wish to show, you will be much better off pre-caching the geocodes than requesting the coding on the fly for a few reasons. First, user-experience-wise, it will be alot quicker because you are removing an entire blocking remote request from the system. Second, the client-side geocoding has a number of rate limitations so it is not reliable if you wish to throw a dozen or so addresses at it at once. Trust me, I learned that one the hard way.

Comment: thank you. I just want to know how to added an address without submitting it

Comment: which you should be able to do based on either example you linked to . . .

Comment: in the demo example I have a function. don't know how to display to function without call it by: onclick() attribute

Comment: You just call the function from your JavaScript.